# Will a car battery break small electronic equipment?

Tags: batteries

I have a 12V car battery. I'd like to run a small wireless router type device on it for a couple of hours. The wireless router has "12V 1A max" written on it.

Will the car battery damage the router, or will it just draw the current it needs and work okay?

Comment: Consumer electronics support is off-topic here. Your answer does already exist on [su] though [here](http://superuser.com/questions/106792/does-a-power-supply-draw-only-as-much-power-as-it-needs).

Comment: @Kortuk - This sounds like an EE question to me.

Comment: I am pretty sure the car battery will break the wireless router if dropped on it.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, hey, can I plug a car battery into my router sounds like an EE question? That is an electronics design question?

Comment: **VAST** amount of EE stuff to be leartned here. It SHOULD be well answered already but if so a ref would be nice. This is an ongoing misunderstanding.

Comment: @Dave - Car battery should be OK. 1A is the most it wants - not the limit of the supply. 12V IS a limit that matters. Ensure polarity is correct !!! (+ to +, - to -). Do not charge battery while router is connected "to be safe".

Comment: "1A max" means "the router will not drain more than 1A", so the fact that the battery can supply more should not matter. However car batteries are only rated at 12V but in fact a fully charged battery can output something like 13,5V under weak load, so I guess that might be a problem. This is the thing I'm sure in on-topic on this site and I believe the question should be reopened.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, it's totally about understanding how loads draw current and how supplies supply it. This is one thing which a great many people misunderstand about electricity. It should be re-opened. I would like to answer it.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, This goes back to the old issue. Just because it is consumer electronics that an EE knows well does not make it an EE question.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, If you would post a broader question discussing the amperage rating of power supplies and answer why it just discusses a maximum it would be useful to close all of these questions as duplicate. It is not an example of electronics design here, this is supporting consumer electronics.

Comment: @sharptooth, I think all of the EEs know that but this is consumer electronics support, as normal EEs are good at many of those questions but that does not make it on topic. The more of these questions we have the more users looking for advice will show up from google. The site will slowing become consumer electronics support.

Comment: @Kortuk - It is *not* computer electronics support! The question has nothing to do with the particular device he's connecting to the battery. It has only to do with how loads draw current.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, Consumer electronics. He wants to know if his consumer electronics will support a 12V battery instead of a 12V charger.

Comment: @Kortuk: To me it's more like "will a car battery be a replacement for a 12V mains adapter for a low power electronic device?".

Comment: @sharptooth, Yes, we said the same thing to me. I want to know if I can use this other thing to plug into this plug. The core issue is the thought that loads will draw the current and voltage rating. The [su] question I linked to previously covers this.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet even if it is all about current draw on a battery, that question has already be asked and answered and a few different forms so it would just be closed as a duplicate.